# java hash map behavior for different key but same hash code

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

As in HashMap there are buckets internally to hold key value pairs.

For the case of keys which have same hash code.

For instance hash code of "abcdef" and "abcdfG" is same.

```
map.put("abcdef", 1);
map.put("abcdfG", 2);
```

When they are put in hash map Entry object gets created where both are placed in same bucket and next of one Entry points to other one.

The question is how will get behave ? When we do map.get("abcdef"); will it give 1 or 2

Comment: it will first use hashCode to resolve bucket and then it will traverse through binary tree to get to exact key and then it will get value once exact key is found

Comment: Why didn't you try it out or read the javadoc? That's not only 1 but 2 obvious and simple ways of getting the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`map.get("abcdef")` will return the correct value (1), since it will use `equals` method to compare each key in the bucket (that matches the hashCode of the key) to the given key, until it finds an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

it will first use `hashcode()` to resolve bucket and then it will traverse through balanced tree to get to exact key and then it will get value once exact key is found

depending on the version of runtime you use, it would be LinkedList or Balanced tree

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

Comment: Binary tree? Singly linked list, no?

Comment: @Boris sorry balanced tree, That was replaced by balanced  tree with http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

Comment: Interesting - didn't know they had changed the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jigar can u please provide me a link to detailed explanation of the fact of linked list or balanced tree, how it gets created during the time of collision and other in depth details related to this.

Comment: This explains nicely http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/04/hashmap-performance-improvements-in.html

Comment: @JigarJoshi It actually switches from a linked list to a balanced tree only when the bucket exceeds a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

The internal buckets are only used by java to help reduce the number of items it needs to search.  You can push everything in the same bucket (with a different key).  The result is just your program will be slower.